# Navigation not loading all pages correctly

Tags: php, html, css, navigation, indexing

Everytime I try to go to my team.html or schedule.html in my navigation bar I am shown my index page. Even though the browser states that the page is correct. Here is the example: http://www.hidesertheat.com/ and http://www.hidesertheat.com/team.html

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

navigation code:

```
<!--A Design by W3layouts
Author: W3layout
Author URL: http://w3layouts.com
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hi Desert Heat Football</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Six+Caps' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="web/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- start slider -->
<link href="web/css/camera.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript">     </script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='web/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='web/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='web/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='web/js/camera.min.js'></script> 
<script language="javaScript">
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){

        jQuery('#camera_wrap_1').camera({
            thumbnails: false
        });

        jQuery('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
            height: '400px',
            loader: 'bar',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: false
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- start header_menu -->
<div class="header_menu">
<div class="main_top">
<div class="wrap">

<div class="headerlogo_tag"><a href="/index.html"><img src="http://www.hidesertheat.com/test/web/images/logo.png" width="174" height="174" alt=""/></a></div>
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div class="cssmenu">
  <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>      
       <li><a href="http://www.hidesertheat.com/news/"><span>News</span></a> </li>
       <li><a href="http://www.hidesertheat.com/team.html"><span>Team</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contactanchor"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the content of those three files (index.html, team.html, schedule.html) is the same, or there is a rule in the .htaccess file that tells team.html and schedule.html to show index.html

Comment: The content is completely different. I have this for the .htaccess    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: What actually happened is the index.php told the server to default to index.html until told otherwise. Once I added the team and schedule to the index.php it worked!

Answer (score 0):

OMG i've just seen your server. its completely messed up. you have a folder called team.html. so when you try to open team.html file in your website it will search for the index file of the team.html filder. i don't know why does any one name a server folder with .html extension.
eg: your schedule.html file is located in http://www.hidesertheat.com/schedule.html/schedile.html so when you type http://www.hidesertheat.com/schedule.html in the browser it will search for index.html in the http://www.hidesertheat.com/schedule.html folder. if you want to see real schedule.html you have to type http://www.hidesertheat.com/schedule.html/schedile.html But you wil have to reset css files as well.

Here is the best solution.
get all your .html files to public_html folder of the server. delete all the folders with the name have ".html"

there are at least 2 folders with ".html". one is team.html(folder), other one is schedile.html(folder), delete those folders from the server and place your team.html(html file) and schedile.html(html file) there instead.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! While moving the files from the web folder did help the team and schedule link appear, now I am faced with another issue. The mobile site has now stopped working and an error appears stating Error: couldnot get Form object contactform. Any suggestions?